# How do I search a database and print results?

Tags: python, django

What I'm looking to do is make it to where I can search the database directly without having the entire database visible on search page.  The search page should be empty. You do a search and it goes straight to the detail page of the db entry which matches your search criteria. If there is no match it shows "No matches found". How can I do this?

This is what I have so far. This prints/lists every entry in the database on the same page as my search box and when a search is done the list gets cut down to however many entries match the search criteria. Every db entry has a link you can click on which will take you to a detail page which pulls up that entry's info.

I'm using Django 2.0.

#### Manage.py

```
class PostManager(models.Manager): 
    def active(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PostManager, self).filter(draft=False).filter(publish__lte=timezone.now())

def upload_location(instance, filename):                
    return "%s/%s" %(instance.slug, filename)               

class Remote(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    orig = models.TextField()
    comp = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location,
    null=True, blank=True, default=0,
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
objects = PostManager() 

def __str__(self):
    return self.model

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("mainapp:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
    slug = slugify(instance.model) #slugify title
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    qs = Remote.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by("-id") 
    exists = qs.exists() 
    if exists: 
        new_slug = "%s-%s" %(slug, qs.first().id) 
    return create_slug(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug 

def pre_save_post_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = create_slug(instance)
pre_save.connect(pre_save_post_receiver, sender=Remote)
```

#### Views.py

```
def detail(request, slug=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Remote, slug=slug)
    share_string = quote_plus(instance.orig)
    context={
        "model": instance.model,
        "instance": instance, 
        "share_string": share_string,
    }
return render(request, 'mainapp/remote_detail.html', context)

def remote_list(request):
    today = timezone.now().date()
    queryset_posts = Remote.objects.all()
    if request.user.is_staff or request_user_is_superuser:
        queryset_posts = Remote.objects.all()

query = request.GET.get("q") # search stuff
    if query:
        queryset_posts = queryset_posts.filter(
            Q(model__icontains=query)|      
            Q(orig__icontains=query)    
            ).distinct() #.distinct() doesn't allow duplicates to show up

paginator = Paginator(queryset_posts,10) # Show 25 contacts per page
page_request_var = "pagina" #this changes "Page name in pagination
page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
queryset = paginator.get_page(page)

context={
    "object_list": queryset,
    "title": "List",
    "page_request_var": page_request_var,
    "today": today,
}
return render(request, 'mainapp/remote_list.html', context)
```

#### HTML for Remote_list view

```
    <form class='mb-2' method='GET' action=''>
    <input type='text' name='q' placeholder='Search posts' value='{{  request.GET.q }}'/> 
    <input href='{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}' type='submit' value='Search'/>
    </form>
{% for obj in object_list %}
{% if obj.image %}
    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ obj.image.url }}" alt="Image" style="max-width:100px;">
{% endif %}  

<h5 class="card-title"><a href='{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}'>{{ obj.model }}</a></h5>
{% if obj.user.get_full_name %}
<p>Author: {{ obj.user.get_full_name }}</p>
{% endif %}
<p class="card-text">{{ obj.orig|truncatechars:120 }}</p>
<a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
{% endfor %}
```

#### HTML for Detail view

```
{% if instance.image %}
<img src='{{ instance.image.url }}' class='img-responsive' style='max-width:300px;' />
{% endif %}
<h3>{{ instance.brand}} {{ model }}</h3>
{% if instance.user.get_full_name %} 
<p>Author: {{ instance.user.get_full_name }}</p>
{% endif %}
<h5>Originally Supplied With: </h5> {{ instance.orig }} 
{% if instance.comp %}
<h5>Compatible With: </h5>{{ instance.comp }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've gone through a few tutorials on youtube.  The tutorial that has gotten me the closest is the "try django 1.9" by "CodingEntrepreneurs" which has 38 videos.  Being that im so new to this I should have followed the instructors advice and followed along with django 1.9 but i used 2.0 instead which made it a nightmare to follow along. My site currently looks like this tutorial and has the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add some codes to your qs but now it's okey
you need to learn more about filtering query and passing them to your views if your models contains title field you can do {{ your_data.title }} in your template  with your_data is the filtered passed query